# The need for pure in Applicatives

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm learning Haskell's Applicatives. It seems to me (I'm probably wrong) that the `pure` function is not really needed, for example:

```
pure (+) <*> [1,2,3] <*> [3,4,5]
```

can be written as

```
(+) <$> [1,2,3] <*> [3,4,5]
```

Can someone explain the benefit that the `pure` function provides over explicit mapping with `fmap`?

Comment: You are correct — `pure f <*> x` is exactly the same as `fmap f x`. I am sure that there is some reason why `pure` was included in `Applicative`, but I’m not entirely sure why.

Comment: I don't have time for an answer, and not convinced this would make a good or complete one anyway, but one observation: `pure` allows one to use, well, "pure" values in an Applicative computation. While, as you correctly observe, `pure f <*> x` is the same as `f <$> x`, there is no such equivalent for, say, `f <*> x <*> pure y <*> z`. (At least I don't think so.)

Comment: As another, more theoretical, justification - there is an [alternative formulation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Alternative_formulation) which relates it closely to the important `Monoid` class - in which `pure` corresponds to `Monoid`'s identity element. (This suggests that `Applicative` without `pure` could be interesting, since `Semigroup` - which is a `Monoid` without necessarily having an identity - still is used. Actually, now I think about it, I seem to recall PureScript has exactly such an "Applicative without `pure`" class, although I don't know what it's used for.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond `fmap (\f' x' z' -> f' x' y z') f <*> x <*> z`, I think. The idea is in the `Applicative` documentation as the law of "interchange".

Comment: @RobinZigmond `Applicative` without `pure` exists as [`Apply` from *semigroupoids*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.3.4/docs/Data-Functor-Apply.html#g:2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm at the edge of my competency here, so don't take this for more than it is, but it was a bit too long for a comment.

There may be practical reasons to include `pure` in the type class, but many Haskell abstractions are derived from theoretical foundations, and I believe that that's the case for `Applicative` as well. As the documentation says, it's a *strong lax monoidal functor* (see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/12412/56098 for a elaboration). I suppose that `pure` serves as the *identity*, just like `return` does for `Monad` (which is a *monoid in the category of endofunctors*).

Consider `pure` and `liftA2`:

```
pure :: a -> f a
liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
```

If you squint a little, you may be able to imagine that `liftA2` is a binary operation, which is also what the documentation states:

> Lift a binary function to actions.

`pure`, then, is the corresponding identity.

Comment: Exactly. `Applicative` without `pure` would be a, hm, _semigroupal_ functor instead of a monoidal one.

Answer (score 21):

`fmap` doesn't always cut it. Specifically, `pure` is what lets you introduce `f` (where `f` is `Applicative`) when you don't already have it. A good example is

```
sequence :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
```

It takes a list of "actions" producing values and turns it into an action producing  a list of values. What happens when there are no actions in the list? The only sane result is an action that produces no values:

```
sequence [] = pure [] -- no way to express this with an fmap
-- for completeness
sequence ((:) x xs) = (:) <$> x <*> sequence xs
```

If you didn't have `pure`, you'd be forced to require a nonempty list of actions. You could definitely make it work, but it's like talking about addition without mentioning 0 or multiplication without 1 (as others have said, because `Applicative`s are monoidal). You will repeatedly run into edge cases that would be easily solved with `pure` but instead have to be solved by weird restrictions on your inputs and other band-aids.